# If Datetime value = null then use today's date

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, datepicker

I'm trying to get it that if no date is selected on the datepicker that instead of submitting null it will submit todays date.

as you can see from the below code I've already tried a number of ways but to no success, there is no viewmodel and it is all on a single page which if I select a date on the datepicker it has no problem.

view page date code

```
<div class="rowElem">
    <label for="Date">Date</label>
    <div id="cal" style="float:left;"></div>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(h => Model.Date)%>
</div>
```

Jquery datepicker code

```
$('#cal').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            [setDefaults: ({ defaultDate: '-0d' }),
            defaultDate: '-0d', tried both this and above line and neither worked]
            onSelect: function (dt, inst) {
                $('#Date').val(dt);
            }
        });
```

Controller create post code for date

```
oq.Date = DateTime.Parse(fc["Date"]);
```

Comment: Update code example to describe variables, where they come from and in what context they are used. Have you read from database, are you reading from query parameters or what are you reading? It is not 100 % clear as it should be (or as close as possible) when you ask your question.

Comment: apart from [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection fc)
        {
            OPEQuestionnaire oq = new OPEQuestionnaire();
            {    the only extra bit of info I would be able to provide is that in the database I had it accepting nulls but james was able to figure out a solution either way

Comment: I surpose the only other thing which would be now useful on this topic is if there is a jquery solution like if what code needs to be changed or added to the datepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Parse` you could use `TryParse`:

```
DateTime tmp = DateTime.MinValue;
oq.Date = DateTime.TryParse(fc["Date"], out tmp) ? tmp : DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: this , out tmp)) should be , out tmp) then all the errors go away and if I didn't have the errors I would of commented sooner on this. Edit- oh yeh and I needed to change fs to be fc

Comment: Kinda surprised that with so many views this topic and it's answers have received so few votes.

Comment: well thx for the +1, was just looking through my questions and with this question having at this moment now 153 views, 6 user answers and only 9 upvotes 3 of which being mine I found it a little strange.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your C#:

```
DateTime date;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(fc["Date"], out date))
    date = DateTime.Today;

oq.Date = date;
```

Edited: based on Myzifer's comment.

Comment: Why use `if (something != true)`? looks weird.

Comment: Error 4 A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter   Error 5 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.TryParse(string, out System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments   Error 6 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out System.DateTime?' to 'out System.DateTime'   doesn't seem to like it one bit

Comment: @Myzifer: You never mentioned that your `oq.DateTime` parameter was a nullable date time. I have updated my answer to suit.

Comment: @Myzifer: Updated for a nullable DateTime

Comment: sorry still new to things so don't know exactly what has knock on effect and where, if (oq.Date == null)
                { oq.Date = DateTime.Now; }
                else
                { oq.Date = DateTime.Parse(fc["Date"]); }  this worked but going to try your way in case that does too and will get bk to ya.  Ok that recorded 0001-01-01 so I guess I'll just post up my comment as the answer which I was able to figure out from everybody else's answers.

Comment: Error 4 Property or indexer 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: @Danny and @Jackson: I agree that `!= true` looks weird, but I'm not sure `!DateTime.TryParse(....)` looks better... I would go for `! == false`. I used to have the `!` before to, but it is easier to miss those than specifying `x == false` or `x == true`. However, `x != false` always make you think a couple of seconds extra when it is not necessary.

Comment: tried to add in the != false to  [, out date)!= false] but it still doesn't like the [oq.Date.Value = date;], don't I need to assign to oq.Date   .HasValue 1st before I can use .Value?

Comment: @Tomas: If your concern is readability then I would recommend storing the value in a local variable e.g. `bool IsValidDate = DateTime.TryParse("dateStr", out tempDate)`. Personally I think my answer using the conditional operator is very clear.

Comment: @James: I agree, your solution is readable in my opinion, and I think people in general should learn to use the ternary operator. When don't like is logic like `x != false`... why not use `x == true` instead. And the `!` operator in the beginning of if statements could be hard to spot sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (oq.Date == null)
            { oq.Date = DateTime.Now; }
            else
            { oq.Date = DateTime.Parse(fc["Date"]); }
```

This worked, was able to figure it out thx to Tomas Jansson and Jackson Popes answers.

Comment: Once I get enough points to vote up I'll vote up your answers Tomas Jansson and Jackson Popes.

Comment: Should of known it wouldn't be so easy since now it doesn't accept a inputted answer and only accepts todays date

Comment: But if any of our answers were the one that helped you, you should accept one of those as the one the fixed your problem. However, I think James solution is the most elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just solve it on server side? If null is submitted use todays date:

```
if(fs["Date"] == null)
   oq.Date = DateTime.Now;
else
   oq.Date = DateTime.Parse(fc["Date"]);
```

Also, you should really have more descriptive names on your variables. Maybe someone else will read your code in the future.

Comment: it still says it's null but goes into else statement just to tell me it's not a valid DateTime.

Comment: It still says what is null? Is `fc` null? `oq` null? Try to be as specific as you can when you write question etc. And as I said, use descriptive variable names... Instead of `fc` use `formCollection` if that what it is.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection fc)
        {
            OPEQuestionnaire oq = new OPEQuestionnaire();
            {     oq.date was showing as null

Comment: Is `oq.date` a `DateTime`? Or is it `DateTime?`, that is, a nullable `DateTime`. And when is it null? Is it null after the if-else statement? That is very odd since both the if and the else sets the value.

Comment: in the sql database it's datatype is date and it allows nulls otherwise it is always refered to as DateTime as my controller code shows, I have the db allowing nulls for date not because I want to store a null but because in previous projects it has helped before I reached a finished stage

Comment: I'm really sorry... but I really don't understand your problem anymore. If you have a parameter from a request, just check to see if it is there and not null. If that is true set the value you want to set, otherwist use your default date value (DateTime.Now). And if it is a database parameter you are reading you can do the same, it shouldn't be that hard to accomplish.

Comment: I used ur code again and it accepted it if I selected a value but if I didn't then it would still come back with FormatException was unhandled by user code String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I think for this to work you need to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` rather than just null. If no date is supplied I assume the form collection is returning an empty string (which is not the same as null)

Comment: @James: Hard to tell from the problem description but you are probably right. :)

Comment: @Tomas: I agree the description/detail provided is far from clear, but if the check is never being hit then I assume there must be *something* in there.

Answer (score 0):

Where does fc come from.If its is a database question you could probably use isnull(fieldname, getdate()) or similary function to have it return today if field is null.

Mysql uses ifnull instead of isnull.

Comment: fc stands for FormCollection since the datepicker is part of a form

Answer (score 0):

Before assigning the date passed from a post request, validate the date data to see if it is not a correct value and set it to today's date else use the post data, if correct.